# WP_HOME (and WP_URL) are undefined

Tags: dashboard, constants, site-health-widget

My site's working, but there's a "cannot complete a loopback request" error in the (dashboard) Tools/Site_Health window I'm tracking down.

My installation is in a subdirectory on my server:
`/home/public_html/my-site/wordpress`

I have, in my (dashboard) Settings/General window:

`WordPress Address (URL)  https://my-site/wordpress` and
`Site Address (URL)  https://my-site`

BUT: this doesn't agree with the WordPress Constants listed in the (dashboard) Tools/Site_Health (info) window:
`ABSPATH    /home/public_html/my-site/wordpress/`
and `WP_HOME    Undefined`
and `WP_SITEURL Undefined`

Any clues as to how to make WordPress "globally aware" of these settings?

Comment: Those constants are not set to the value of those settings. So unless you manually defined them in wp-config.php you shouldn't expect to see a value. Regardless, those settings aren't why you would have issues with loopback requests. That's an issue with the server configuration. You will need to speak to your host.